# Refreshing webpart view automatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have a document library called **'Client Documents'** that has a column called **'Client'** and **'Document Type'**, when a user uploads a document to the library they select a client for example **'Microsoft'** and then the document type **'Network Diagram'**

I then created a view called **'Microsoft Network Diagrams'** that filters the company name **'Microsoft'** and the document type **'Network Diagrams'** to just show me the documents for that client.

I then created a page with a webpart that connects to the document library **'Client Documents'** and then I select the view **'Microsoft Network Diagrams'** from the webpart options which works as expected.

The problem I have is if I make a change the to view I have to edit the webpart and re-select the view for it to update.

Is there a way for the view to update automatically on the page?

Answer (score 0):

The changes made in the original view will not reflect in the webpart as the copy of the view in webpart is different from original one.

**Update**

The sample code to update the view of `XsltListViewWebPart`. Note that I haven't tested the code. You can create a console app, test the code and then use the .exe in task schedueler

```
// Get refrerence of the page containing the xslt list view webpart
SPFile page = web.GetFile("PageUrl");
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart = null;
// Check if webpart is on the page or not
SPLimitedWebPartCollection webPartCollection = wpm.WebParts;
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart part in webPartCollection)
{
    if (part.Title.Equals(webPartTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {       
        XsltListViewWebPart wp = (XsltListViewWebPart)part;
        // Get the list
        SPList list = web.Lists["ListTitle"];
        // Update the view of list view webpart
        wp.View = list.View["ViewName"];
        wp.View.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is now way around this to allow the view to be updated?

Comment: The code can written inside a task scheduler or timer job to update the view as per the timing requirements.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, thanks for the reply, can you explain how to create this with the correct code

Comment: @MattSaunders see my updated answer